# Django Rest framework + EmberJS File upload update(patch)

Tags: django, ember.js, ember-data, django-rest-framework

I have a model like this:

```
// models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    someboolean = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    someotherBoolean = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    myfilefield = models.FileField(upload_to='/files/')
```

Then i have a serializer like this:

```
// serializers.py
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Then i have a View which inherit from `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`

This Django Rest setup is connected to the EmberJS and is running ok. The data from the server is retrived without any problem and the `myfilefield` content is represented like a `string` in ember which is a url to the actual file. When i think of uploading a file to the field on the Django Rest side it seems that i have to play a little with FileUploadParser to make it right and i think this is not much more lines of code into it.

But the issue is that my model on the Ember side should be updated in parts. Sometimes i need to update only the value of `someboolean` and do not send any files to `myfilefield` either because the file is already there or because this is done in the other UI iteration (separately). When in Ember i call `this.get('model').save();` after some change to the `someboolean` is made it sends the whole model data back to django rest and the `myfilefield` in this json request is represented as a string and not as file thus the server returns an error.

As i understand there could be some workarounds to this situation:

1. The first would be to create custom `serializers.CustomFileField` which checks whether the provided `string` is equal to the url which is generated by the serializer on the output and if it is just leaves the file intact.
2. Second option would be to somehow implement the quick and dirty `patch` on the ember side which as i understand is still thing under development according to [This Link](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/5). But this option seems to be quite hard as i have a lot of models with filefields and i should implement the `patch` method in ember for each and every one of them.
3. The third option as i forsee would be to create a special `File` model like so:

   //models.py
   class File(models.Model):
       filebody = models.FileField(upload_to='/files/')

and make the `myfilefield` on the MyModel `read_only` so it won't validate at any time. I could also implement some method on the `File` model which would recieve the model and instance for which this file really belongs and after upload and validation would make the `myfilefield = filebody` 
This method also seems very dirty but at least keeps some concepts abstracts so i wouldn't need to worry how many models with `FileFields` i actually have in my project.

My UI expects the user to do the change to one model field at a time and then save the model - i.e. 
1. change the name field, save the model.
2. change the boolean field, save the model.
3. upload file, save the model.

Any suggestions on what would be the best way in terms of django rest to accomplish this considering the fact that ember still does not support `PATCH` requests.

Comment: So is this truly a mismatch between ember-data (or ember-model) ? I only ask because raw ember would work (you would just need to write the xhr/patch code yourself)

Comment: I believe this is an ember-data issue. You can read about it here: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/json-patch-support-for-ember-data/6078 After some more research i have found that `PATCH` is documented under JSON API which is currently implemented in the form of addons: ember-json-api adapter as well as rest-framework-json-api . However they are still on the very early stage.

Comment: @canufeel as the developer of the DRF side of that, I can tell you that the Ember side is looking pretty good and, if you have some spare time, the DRF side can catch up.

Comment: @KevinBrown i will try to. As for now i see that rest-framework-json-api has some troubles dealing with fields that have required=False set on them. Will try to investigate on this issue further.